# Overriding an existing file in C#

Tags: c#, file

revised!

I want to create a file say called test.txt.

if that file already exists I want to create file called test1.txt and so on.

Comment: @Peter - not sure why you assume this is homework, it's quite reasonable that a real application might need to do this

Comment: I removed the tag, cause i might not have understood the question

Comment: Perhaps the question would be more clear if it said "so that it will be overwritten?"

Answer (score 30):

Pass in `FileMode.Create` to `File.Open(string, FileMode)` when opening the file and it will create a new file every time.

```
FileStream file = File.Open("text.txt", FileMode.Create);
```

Answer (score 1):

The classes in System.IO should help you do that.

```
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a short example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String file = "text.txt"; 

        if (File.Exists(file))
            File.Delete(file);

        FileStream fs = File.Create(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use File.Exists for this. Who's to say something doesn't create a file in between File.Exists, File.Delete and File.Create?